# Pandas operation by row condition

Tags: python, pandas

I'm stuck with this bathymetry data gathered from a Echo-sounder.
It looks like this:

```
ID No Time Lat Lon Alt East North Count Fix
LL 0 589105179.00 24.156741 -110.321346 -31.50 4898039.453 -3406895.053 9 2 
ED 0 1.12 0.00
ED 0 1.53 0.00
ED 0 1.60 0.00
ED 0 1.08 0.00
ED 0 1.51 0.00
ED 0 1.06 0.00
LL 0 589105180.00 24.156741 -110.321346 -31.50 4898039.836 -3406894.045 9 2
ED 0 1.06 0.00
ED 0 1.12 0.00
ED 0 0.98 0.00
ED 0 0.96 0.00
ED 0 0.91 0.00
ED 0 0.90 0.00
LL 0 589105181.00 24.156741 -110.321346 -31.50 4898039.433 -3406894.003 9 2
ED 0 1.04 0.00
ED 0 1.04 0.00
ED 0 0.93 0.00
ED 0 0.99 0.00
ED 0 0.99 0.00
ED 0 1.01 0.00
LL 0 589105182.00 24.156741 -110.321346 -31.51 4898038.460 -3406894.841 9 2
ED 0 0.99 0.00
ED 0 0.96 0.00
ED 0 0.96 0.00
ED 0 0.96 0.00
ED 0 0.98 0.00
ED 0 0.98 0.00
LL 0 589105183.00 24.156741 -110.321346 -31.51 4898039.804 -3406894.107 9 2
ED 0 1.01 0.00
ED 0 1.01 0.00
ED 0 0.91 0.00
ED 0 1.04 0.00
ED 0 1.04 0.00
ED 0 0.96 0.00
```

Every LL row gives time (seconds since year 2000), coordinates, direction, etc. for the next ED rows bathymetry measure.

We need to calculate the mean of every ED measure and assign it to the LL row. The problem is that in the complete file ED measures are not always 6, sometimes 5 or 4.

So far I've done this:

```
data = pd.read_csv('Echosounder.txt', sep = '\t')    
LLs = data[data['ID'] == 'LL']    
EDs = data[data['ID'] == 'ED']
```

What I like about this is that it respects the index order.
I noticed that there are different number of ED measures because after doing this:

```
EDs.groupby(np.arange(len(EDs))//6).mean()
```

and appending them to LLs, the last LL rows don't have bathymetry values.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the time in each LL row is unique. You can use it as a grouping key. First, create a new grouping column that equals Time for all LL rows:

```
data.loc[data['ID']=='LL', 'key'] = data['Time']
```

Propagate the most recent value of each key to the ED rows:

```
data['key'].ffill(inplace=True)
```

Group by the new key and join the results with the `LLs` DataFrame:

```
LLs.set_index('Time')\
   .join(data[data['ID']=='ED']\
         .groupby('key').mean()[['No','Time','Lat']], rsuffix='_mean')
#             ID  No        Lat    ...     No_mean      Time  Lat_mean
#Time                              ...                                
#589105179.0  LL   0  24.156741    ...           0  1.316667       0.0
#589105180.0  LL   0  24.156741    ...           0  0.988333       0.0
#589105181.0  LL   0  24.156741    ...           0  1.000000       0.0
#589105182.0  LL   0  24.156741    ...           0  0.971667       0.0
#589105183.0  LL   0  24.156741    ...           0  0.995000       0.0
```

The last three columns are the means.

Answer (score 0):

DYZ has a great answer. Alternatively, if you didn't want to assume the times are unique, you could use the index in a similar fashion.

```
data['dummy'] = np.nan
data.loc[data['ID']=='LL', 'dummy'] = data.loc[data['ID']=='LL', 'dummy'].index
data['dummy'].ffill(axis=0, inplace=True)


LLs.set_index('dummy')\
     .join(data[data['ID']=='ED']\
     .groupby('dummy').mean()[['No','Time','Lat']], rsuffix='_mean')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to iterate over each item and add the timestamp to the LD rows.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep='\t', index_col=False)

df.head()


ID  No  Time    Lat Lon Alt East    North   Count   Fix timestamp   ed_value
0   LL  0   5.891052e+08    24.156741   -110.321346 -31.5   4898039.453 -3406895.053    9.0 2.0 589105179.0 NaN
1   ED  0   1.120000e+00    0.000000    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 589105179.0 1.12
2   ED  0   1.530000e+00    0.000000    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 589105179.0 1.53
3   ED  0   1.600000e+00    0.000000    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 589105179.0 1.60
4   ED  0   1.080000e+00    0.000000    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 589105179.0 1.08

LLs = df[df['ID'] == 'LL']    
EDs = df[df['ID'] == 'ED']

for x in df.iterrows():
    if x[1]['ID'] == 'LL':
        timestamp = x[1]['Time']
    elif x[1]['ID'] == 'ED':
        df.loc[x[0], 'ed_value'] = x[1]['Time']
    df.loc[x[0], 'timestamp'] = timestamp

df.groupby('timestamp').mean()

    No  Time    Lat Lon Alt East    North   Count   Fix ed_value
timestamp                                       
589105179.0 0   8.415788e+07    3.450963    -110.321346 -31.50  4898039.453 -3406895.053    9.0 2.0 1.316667
589105180.0 0   8.415788e+07    3.450963    -110.321346 -31.50  4898039.836 -3406894.045    9.0 2.0 0.988333
589105181.0 0   8.415788e+07    3.450963    -110.321346 -31.50  4898039.433 -3406894.003    9.0 2.0 1.000000
589105182.0 0   8.415788e+07    3.450963    -110.321346 -31.51  4898038.460 -3406894.841    9.0 2.0 0.971667
589105183.0 0   8.415788e+07    3.450963    -110.321346 -31.51  4898039.804 -3406894.107    9.0 2.0 0.995000
```

Answer (score 0):

Two answers.  This first one assumes each LL row has ED rows associated with it.

```
import numpy as np

IDcount = data.ID.values
b, c = np.unique(IDcount, return_inverse=True)
g = np.cumsum(c)
df['grps'] = g
mean_vals = \
    data[data.ID == 'ED'][['ID', 'grps', 'Time']].groupby(['ID', 'grps']).mean().Time.values
df2 = data[data.ID == 'LL'].copy()
df2['ED_mean'] = mean_vals
```

df2:

```
    ID  No         Time       Lat           Lon    Alt         East       North  Count  Fix grp ED_mean
0   LL  0   589105179.0 24.156741   -110.321346 -31.50  4898039.453 -3406895.053    9.0 2.0 1   1.316667
7   LL  0   589105180.0 24.156741   -110.321346 -31.50  4898039.836 -3406894.045    9.0 2.0 2   0.988333
14  LL  0   589105181.0 24.156741   -110.321346 -31.50  4898039.433 -3406894.003    9.0 2.0 3   1.000000
21  LL  0   589105182.0 24.156741   -110.321346 -31.51  4898038.460 -3406894.841    9.0 2.0 4   0.971667
28  LL  0   589105183.0 24.156741   -110.321346 -31.51  4898039.804 -3406894.107    9.0 2.0 5   0.995000
```

-

-

Here is a similar answer which will correctly allow for cases where there are no ED rows for an LL row.  This is not quite as fast as the first answer.

```
remove_idx = [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34]
data2 = data.loc[~data.index.isin(remove_idx)].copy()

IDcount = data2.ID.values
b, c = np.unique(IDcount, return_inverse=True)

g = np.cumsum(c)

data['grps'] = g

grouping_df = data2[data2.ID == 'ED'][['ID', 'grps', 'Time']].copy()
grouped = grouping_df.groupby(['ID', 'grps']).mean()
grouped.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
mean_df = grouped[['grps', 'Time']].copy()
mean_df.rename(columns={'Time': 'ED_mean'}, inplace=True)

LLs = data2[data2.ID == 'LL'].copy()

result_df = pd.merge(LLs, mean_df, on='grps', how='outer').set_index(LLs.index)
```

result_df:

```
    ID  No        Time        Lat           Lon    Alt         East North       Count   Fix grps ED_mean
0   LL  0   589105179.0 24.156741   -110.321346 -31.50  4898039.453 -3406895.053    9.0 2.0 1   1.316667
7   LL  0   589105180.0 24.156741   -110.321346 -31.50  4898039.836 -3406894.045    9.0 2.0 2   0.988333
14  LL  0   589105181.0 24.156741   -110.321346 -31.50  4898039.433 -3406894.003    9.0 2.0 3   NaN
21  LL  0   589105182.0 24.156741   -110.321346 -31.51  4898038.460 -3406894.841    9.0 2.0 4   0.971667
28  LL  0   589105183.0 24.156741   -110.321346 -31.51  4898039.804 -3406894.107    9.0 2.0 5   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Parse File

```
from itertools import count
from collections import defaultdict
from pandas.io.common import StringIO as sio
import pandas as pd

c = count()
text = dict(LL=[], ED=defaultdict(list))

with open('file.txt', 'r') as fh:
  cols = fh.readline()

  for line in fh.readlines():
    k, t = line.split(None, 1)

    if k == 'LL':
      i = next(c)
      text[k].append(line)
    else:
      text[k][i].append(t)
```

#### Construct `DataFrame`

```
ll = pd.read_csv(sio('\n'.join([cols, *text['LL']])), delim_whitespace=True)

ed = pd.concat({
    i: pd.read_csv(sio('\n'.join(v)), delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
    for i, v in text['ED'].items()
}).mean(level=0).add_prefix('ed_')

ll.join(ed)
```

---

```
   ID  No         Time        Lat         Lon    Alt         East        North  Count  Fix  ed_0      ed_1  ed_2
0  LL   0  589105179.0  24.156741 -110.321346 -31.50  4898039.453 -3406895.053      9    2     0  1.316667   0.0
1  LL   0  589105180.0  24.156741 -110.321346 -31.50  4898039.836 -3406894.045      9    2     0  0.988333   0.0
2  LL   0  589105181.0  24.156741 -110.321346 -31.50  4898039.433 -3406894.003      9    2     0  1.000000   0.0
3  LL   0  589105182.0  24.156741 -110.321346 -31.51  4898038.460 -3406894.841      9    2     0  0.971667   0.0
4  LL   0  589105183.0  24.156741 -110.321346 -31.51  4898039.804 -3406894.107      9    2     0  0.995000   0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution does not require unique timestamp. Will Add column for mean, plus the original data in separate columns. In case you dont need the "ED measure" values remove everything called ColID.

```
LLs.index = np.arange(LLs.shape[0])

EDs = EDs[['No']]
EDs['MyID'] = np.nan
EDs['ColID'] = np.nan

last_row, new_id, col_id = -1, 0, 1

for row in EDs.iterrows():
    current_row = row[0]

    if current_row == last_row + 1:
        EDs.loc[current_row, 'MyID'] = new_id
        EDs.loc[current_row, 'ColID'] = col_id
        col_id += 1
    else:
        col_id = 1
        new_id += 1
        EDs.loc[current_row, 'MyID'] = new_id

    last_row = current_row

data_mean = pd.DataFrame(EDs.groupby('MyID')['No'].mean())
data_mean.rename(columns={'No': 'Mean'}, inplace=True)
EDs = pd.pivot_table(EDs, values='No', index='MyID', columns='ColID', aggfunc=np.sum)

LLs = LLs.merge(EDs, left_index=True, right_index=True)
LLs = LLs.merge(data_mean, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```